# Ionic 5 - iPhone X (Toolbar tabs not showing correctly)

Tags: ionic-framework

I am working on a Ionic project, but seem to have an error i do not now how to correct.

For some reason on iPhone models above X it makes the ion-tabs look wierd and non-clickable?

does anyone have the same issue?

[tabs look super wierd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iaHRD.png)

Comment: It would be useful if you could post your code of what you have tried so far.

Comment: I think its related to handlinger section header , i think its made using margins and this is causing the tabs to be pushed down but as @E.Maggini said , you should post your code.